# Select2 not getting initialized in bootstrap modal when created dynamically using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I am a popup modal to show dynamic data inside inputs in order to edit, on the same page I am using select2 without any problem, but in the modal it looks that it is not being initialized after load even though jquery is initializing it on success(or that's what it should do) using this modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="company_edit">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div></div></div> </div>
```

and jquery:

```
$('.btn.btn-primary.btn-xs').on('click', function () {
                var company_id = $(this).attr('value');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'dist/php/info_to_edit.php', 
                    data: 'post_id=' + company_id,
                    success: function (r)
                    {
                        $(".select2").select2({
                            tags: true,
                            tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
                        });
                        // now you can show output in your modal 
                        $('#edit').modal('show'); // put your modal id 
                        $('#edit').find('.company_edit').html(r);
                    }});});
```

and the php snippet:

```
echo '<select name="countries_import[]" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" id="import_select"></select>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set

```
$('#edit').find('.company_edit').html(r);
```

before

```
$(".select2").select2({
  tags: true,
  tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
});
```

Comment: yeah i should have been more logical with my script. Thank you that solved my problem.